# How are trustees chosen?

Tags: university, governance

I thought that trustees of a university are leading people in the region or around the country (politicians, industrial leaders, donators, etc). I accidentally saw the [Board of Trustees of Princeton University](http://www.princeton.edu/vpsec/trustees/current/), and was surprised that one of the members is just a student from California.

It makes me wonder, how the trustees are selected? and what are the requirements for becoming a trustee?

Comment: So, exactly how does one 'accidentally' see the Board of Trustees?  Just wondering...

Comment: Two cases that I happen to know about, as an employee or alumnus.  The  University of Michigan has a Board of Regents elected by the voters of the state of Michigan (usually very far down on the ballot, where not too many people bother to vote).  Harvard University has a Board of Overseers elected by Harvard's alumni.

Comment: To be clear, the trustee in question is not "just a student from California"; she graduated from Princeton 4 years ago and subsequently enrolled in a Ph.D. program at Stanford. When you say it this way, it's much less surprising...

Comment: Varies by institution.

Answer (score 6):

Every university should have a [documented process](http://www.princeton.edu/vpsec/trustees/composition/) for choosing trustees, regents, etc. Ours are appointed by the Governor. See the link for what Princeton does. There are students on the Princeton board because a) there was a grad student among the 13 elected alumni trustees (2011 grad), and b) because there is always a graduating senior elected. Both of these kinds of alumni trustees serve for 4-year terms.